# SQL optimize child-parent query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm writing a report using MS Project Server, but I ran into a problem. I need to sum some fields in child-parent hierarchy. The sum is the sum of values in leaves. I wrote a query, but it is working only on small sets of data.

```
Task - 10
  Task - 2
  Task - 6
    Task - 6
  Task - 2

WITH children AS (
SELECT 
tt.ID, 
CASE '1' WHEN ISNULL(ttt.Id, '1') THEN tt.Value ELSE 0 END as Value,
CASE '1' WHEN ISNULL(ttt.Id, '1') THEN tt.Value2 ELSE 0 END as Value2,
tt.parentid
    FROM [MonitoringExampleDatabase].[dbo].[Table_1] tt
    LEFT JOIN [MonitoringExampleDatabase].[dbo].[Table_1] ttt 
    ON tt.ID = ttt.ParentId

UNION ALL

SELECT t.id, children.value, children.Value2, t.parentid
    FROM children 
    JOIN [MonitoringExampleDatabase].[dbo].[Table_1] t ON children.parentid = t.id
)

SELECT  id, sum(value) as Value, SUM(value2) as Value2
    FROM children 
    GROUP BY id
```

Any ideas how to optimize that query, now the problem is limit of recursion.

Comment: Please, specify several sample rows stored in table MonitoringExampleDatabase.

Comment: Yes, if you could provide some sample data, and your expected results, you would get help much faster.

Answer (score 1):

Is the join in the first SELECT of children around the wrong way? If I run your code I just get the data back unsummed:

```
id          Value       Value2
----------- ----------- -----------
1           10          0
2           2           0
3           6           0
4           6           0
5           2           0
```

although this may be due to the way I've set up the table, which is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tasks](
[Id] [int] NULL,
[ParentId] [int] NULL,
[Value] [int] NULL,
[Value2] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

If I refactor the first SELECT of Children like so, I get what I presume are the desired results:

```
WITH children AS (
    SELECT 
      c.ID, 
      c.Value,
      c.Value2,
      c.parentid
    FROM Tasks c
      LEFT JOIN Tasks p
        ON c.ParentId = p.Id

UNION ALL

    SELECT t.id, children.value, children.Value2, t.parentid
        FROM children 
        INNER JOIN Tasks t ON children.parentid = t.id
)

SELECT  id, sum(value) as Value, SUM(value2) as Value2
    FROM children 
    GROUP BY id
```

Results:

```
id          Value       Value2
----------- ----------- -----------
1           26          0
2           2           0
3           12          0
4           6           0
5           2           0
```

Regarding performance, generally speaking recursive algorithms are slow if you have a lot of levels. To get better speed you can refactor to an iterative version, as long as you know the maximum possible number of levels.

The iterative code is not as pretty or succinct as the recursive but probably easier to understand (hence maintain).

Comment: I think this should work fine. One small comment - LEFT JOIN in the first part is unnecessary. You are not selecting anything from Tasks p.

Comment: Good spotting - I was focussed on the refactoring

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)` at the end of your select statement to disable the limit of recursion.

```
WITH children AS 
(
...
)
SELECT  id, sum(value) as Value, SUM(value2) as Value2
FROM children 
GROUP BY id
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx

Comment: I tried `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)`, but query takes 2mins when I kill it. That query has some bug that turn in a loop.

Is there any better way to achive that goal.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't really catch the time to go through your code carefully. I'll take a look at it now - but your first part of CTE - before UNION should only return the top level rows, and bottom part joins them to their children.